# Image Zoom In Mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I A have Situation where I should show two images by default. One image is small and other image is big.

If the user is scrolling on the small image The position where he is zooming in the small image should reflect in big image

I tried with elevate Zoom http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom.
 But shows the image only after the user places cursor on the image

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain it a bit more? Do you want to mark the hovered area in the big image, or actually zoom it? If you want the "zoom" window to stay there you could adjust the js script your using, just search for places where its hidden, or the css value is set to display: none.

you could also use easyzoom, which is a bit better documented: http://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/

Comment: consider there two images in the same view a.jpg(small image) and b.jpg(big image). if the user hovers on a.jpg we should heilght the same part in b.jpg.

Comment: i have seen u r example it consists only one image . on hover it is showing another image which i have done. two images should be shown by default

Comment: then its just as easy as written above. search for the part in the script where it hides the zoom window and disable that part. Then you have the zoom window displayed permanently. Or search for a script that offers that by default. There are a lot scripts for that usecase